# Java web page without servlet?

Tags: java, html, servlets, webserver

I want to build a very simple webpage in Java. In the webpage I want the user to chose a file from his computer to send to the server, in the server i'm doing some editing on the video and send it back. Is there a way to do this without servlets? What's the simplest / easiest solution to this?

Comment: Because I don't know anything about web pages in java and I find them very confusing :/

Comment: You say you want the file to be sent to the server, so,  as a 'controller', using sevlet is recommended.

Comment: You might want to look into some of the availble HTTP frameworks, e.g. [Spark](http://www.sparkjava.com/), [Ratpack](http://www.ratpack.io/) or [Netty](http://netty.io/).

Answer (score 1):

There are many frameworks like **struts and spring**, which are providing direct interceptors for file-upload and more other features. But it needs some good hands in these frameworks.

*If you are new then Servlet would be better.*

Edit: For spring http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

For struts: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_file_uploads.htm

Servlet: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm

Comment: Ok Thanks i'll check them out :)